# Android - Timer and GPS tracking. Should I use a service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am writing and app that has a running timer (updates the UI every 10th of a second like a watch) and also tracks distance via GPS. The intended use case is to have this app run for up to a couple of hours, so it shouldn't ever be killed by the system. Very similar to many of the running applications that you find on the market today (although that isn't what I am making).

That requirement that it should not be killed by the system points me to creating a service, but it seems like communicating the timer and distance updates to the UI that often would be really inefficient.

Would using a service be the best approach here? If so, how do I efficiently handle updating the time and distance on the UI? Or is there another way to keep the system from killing my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided that I will indeed use a service, but only start it up and use it when the activity is paused. The Activity will pass the current state to the service where it will take care of all everything that needs to be done, and when resumed the activity will get the state back from the service and kill it off.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a service unless you require that something is happening even when your app's activity is pushed behind another activity, and when the phone screen turns off. All things being equal, it's better just to have your app smartly pick up when it's resumed.

For example, if you have a stopwatch, you keep track of the start time. When your apps's activity is paused, you stop everything. You stop counting. But when you resume, you know the start time so you can pick up with the correct timings and resume updating the UI.

Just create a timer / thread to update your UI in your activity. Start it in `onResume()` and stop in on `onPause()`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense with the timer, but I don't think it will work for the GPS part. I can store the last know location, but since they may make turns it wouldn't be accurate to simply use that last location when coming back to the Activity.

Comment: you register a location listener inside the activity. you start listening in onResume() and stop in onPause(). if you need to track location when your activity is not in the foreground, right, you need a service.